# WP7 Updating Pivot control title

Tags: data-binding, pivot, windows-phone

I have a Pivot control which I am using as following within the XAML.
I have bound the Pivot Title to a method on my view model as its content will vary depending upon what is being displayed.

```
 <controls:Pivot x:Name="MainPivot" ItemsSource="{Binding PivotItemHeaders}" Title="{Binding ApplicationTitle}"  >
        <controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListBox x:Name="EventsListbox"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding allEventItems}"
                         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource EventDisplay3}"
                         SelectionChanged="EventsListbox_SelectionChanged"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
    </controls:Pivot>
```

The collection of items is being refreshed and the binding is working fine for these objects  - however the Pivot title is not refreshing with the new value.
It seems stuck at the value when the page/pivot control was first shown.

Any ideas how I can get the pivot control to refresh?  - Thanks

Comment: I assume you mean you're binding the pivot title to a Property on your viewmodel, not a method.

Comment: yes .. sorry - you are quite right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did a quick test, binding works just fine:

```
<controls:Pivot Title="MY APPLICATION" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineOne}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
    <controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>      
                <Button Content="Update" Click="Button_Click" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
</controls:Pivot>
```

And in the C#

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    App.ViewModel.Items.Clear();
    App.ViewModel.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "foo" });
    App.ViewModel.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "bar" });
    App.ViewModel.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "baz" });
}
```

So clearly you're doing something very wrong. Post your code and we'll take a look.

**Update**

Title Binding also works

XAML

```
<controls:Pivot Title="{Binding Title}">
    <controls:PivotItem Header="first">
        <Grid>
            <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="OK!" />
        </Grid>
    </controls:PivotItem>
</controls:Pivot>
```

C#:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Title = "foobar!";
    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Title"));
}
```

Comment: Hi  My binding for the content of the pivot control is working fine - it's just the Title of the Pivot control, which is also bound that is not working as I would like.

Comment: But as you see, I also bound the title, which works quite fine. So again, something is wrong with your code. You should post the viewmodel you're binding against, so we can have a look.

Comment: Hi Claus  I will post the viewmodel code...but I dont see any binding for your title?  I can see its set to "MY APPLICATION" rather than being bound.  This is the field that I am trying to manipulate - the pivot item headers are working fine.

Comment: Oh! sorry for the confusion there. However, the binding should still work, regardless. Again, my guess is you're not notifying the viewmodel of the title property being updated.

Comment: Hi Claus  - thanks for sticking with me on this... yes your guess was quite right - not RaisingProprtyChanged in the viewmodel.  It works fine now.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen when I update the view model, the pivot updates too. However, it only update those pivot items which are visible on the screen (the current pivot item, and 1,2 pivot items to the right are updated, but the pivot items to the left, which are not on the screen, is not update). I can see this when I drag it to the left !!